# how to get all my facebook application users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get the list of users who have connected to the app. Is there a way to do it using `FQL` or Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FQL, just do :

```
$fql="SELECT uid FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ".$me['id'].")
AND is_app_user = 1";
```

This is self explanatory.

AFAIK, its not possible via GRAPH API

Comment: I cannot get that FQL statement to work. Can you post an example of its results to check it and prove it still works. Thanks.

Comment: You just want the list of all users who added the app ?

Answer (score 2):

I used this and works fine. This will get you a lists of your friends who have approved the app, not all the users

```
function getUsersApplication(){
    var url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/friends.getAppUsers?access_token="+FB.getAccessToken();
    $.ajax( {
        url : url,
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'text',
        data : null,
        success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this Requires user session

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, here is an AS3 example:

```
var fql:String = "select pic_square, uid, first_name from user where is_app_user = 1 and uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =" + Facebook.getSession().uid + ")";
```